# Multiplication in assembly with negative number and result

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am fairly new in Assembly,
and I am having a hardtime dealing with negative number

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    short int mat1[] = {-1,-2, 4,5, 4,-2}; // first array
    short int mat2[] = {2,0,0,0, 0,2,0,0}; // second array
    int mat3[1024]; // result array

    __asm {
        MOV AX, mat1[0] ; mat1[0]:= -1
        MOV BX, mat2[0] ; mat2[0]:= 2
        ; my problem is how i can do this
        ; mat3[0] = mat1[0] * mat2[0] ;
        ; (operation result -> mat3[0] = -2)
    }
}
```

p.s. This is for my homework 
thanks in advance

---

New Question:

After try some assembly operation:

```
MOV AX, mat1[ECX]   ; eax is 0 and mat1[ecx] is -1
```

but after this operation
how come AX is set to 65535 and not to -1?
How can I do proper multiplication then if AX register is not correct?
I am quite confuse how to handle complement of 2.

---

I got another question.
currently I have this code where I move **IMUL** result to array.

```
    MOV WORD PTR mat3[ECX*4]+0, AX 
    MOV WORD PTR mat3[ECX*4]+2, DX
```

My Question is how can I add the IMUL result to the current Array[idx] value?

with this where mat3[current index] = 0, the operation is correct.
but when for example mat3[current index] = -2, I a different number to what I expect to get.

```
    ADD WORD PTR mat3[ECX*4]+0, AX 
    ADD WORD PTR mat3[ECX*4]+2, DX
```

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: No need to answer. I alredy figured out.

Comment: See also [my answer here about multiplying 16-bit numbers and producing a 32-bit (`int`) result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581293/invalid-instruction-operands-on-mov-ah-word-variable-and-using-imul-on-16-bi/39582213#39582213).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the 8086 architecture, there are two instructions to multiply two numbers, but different arguments can be used:

```
Val8   DB  12      ; 8-bit variable
Val16  DW  12345   ; 16-bt variable

MUL    BL         ; Unsigned multiply of 8-bit register
MUL    [Val8]     ; Unsigned multiply of 8-bit memory location
MUL    BX         ; Unsigned multiply of 16-bit register
MUL    [Val16]    ; Unsigned multiply of 16-bit memory location

IMUL   BL         ; Signed multiply of 8-bit register
IMUL   [Val8]     ; Signed multiply of 8-bit memory location
IMUL   BX         ; Signed multiply of 16-bit register
IMUL   [Val16]    ; Signed multiply of 16-bit memory location
```

But... if it multiplies two variables, where's the second variable? The answer is that the second variable is *always* `AL` for 8-bit multiplies, and *always* `AX` for 16-bit multiplies.

- The result of an 8-bit multiply can be up to 16 bits, so it is *always* stored in `AX`.
- The result of a 16-bit multiply can be up to 32 bits! Uh oh! The 8086 doesn't have 32-bit registers! Where does it store the result? In `DX:AX`. That is, it stores the high 16 bits in `DX`, and the low 16 bits in `AX`.

For your code, instead of moving `mat2[0]` into `BX`, you could simply `IMUL` it directly from memory - and yes, you should use `IMUL` since you want an signed multiply.

Once you have the result of the `IMUL`, you need to store the result in `mat3[0]`. Since you cannot move `DX:AX` with one instruction, you need two. I don't know which assembler you're using, but usually the syntax would be something like this:

```
MOV WORD PTR mat3[0]+0, AX
MOV WORD PTR mat3[0]+2, DX
```

Look at the above carefully! `mat3[0]` is a 32-bit int, so you cannot move a 16-bit register into it. You need to tell the assembler to treat it as `WORD` (16 bits) first. And to store the *high* 16 bits that are in `DX`, you need to put them *after* `AX` in memory, thus the `+2`. (The `+0` in the line before is just for symmetry).

Don't forget: the 8086 stores its multi-byte values with the least significant bytes *first*. That means that you need to store the two parts of the result as I have shown above.

Comment: The OP is clearly using 32-bit code from C++, and not limited to running on 8086.  The two-operand form of imul is very convenient.  Also, the assembler being used is the one built-in to MSVC++.  As I understand it, it's pretty much like MASM.

Comment: @PeterCordes When I first saw the question, it had: an 8086 tag; only x86 instructions; and only original C++ code. These latest edits... change things. Over to you!

Comment: @Macmade D'oh! I can't believe I suffered the copy/paste error like that! Thank you.

Comment: heh, I didn't check the edit history.  That's pretty terrible, and explains a lot about why you answered this way!  Silly OP.

Comment: You shouldn't add questions to an existing one: you should ask a new question. Note that you are not initialising `mat3` - you are adding to whatever random values are already there.