# scalar product of 2 arrays with the length of a variable nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

Hey guys I am using x64 assembly
I want to declare variable in the memory called lengthx and then I want to initialize 2 arrays that the length of each array is lengthx times that contains numbers
and then the program needs to calculates the scalar product of A and B and insert the the result into resultx variable

I did my research and all I found was people adding externs and I don't want any externs and all I saw that people were saying its not a nasm syntax it's a fasm syntax I saw people using the `time` but that didnt work for me
this is my bad code

```
%include "io64.inc"
section .data
length db 5
Table_A DB 10, 5, 2,3,1
Table_B DB 1,3,2,1,2
result db 0
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
MOV SI, Table_A     ;POINTER TO TABLE_A.
MOV DI, Table_B     ;POINTER TO TABLE_B.
MOV CX, length           ;ARRAY LENGTH.
myloop:
   
   MOV Ax, [SI]
    MOV [DI], Ax
    add [result],DI
    add [result],SI
    inc SI
    inc DI
    loop myloop
    
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

apricate any help

Comment: This code can't even assemble because 64-bit mode doesn't allow 16-bit address-size.  Use 64-bit registers for pointers, like RSI.  Also, decide what size your element should be.  You used `db` for your data, but 16-bit operand-size (AX) to load and store, but only incremented your pointers by 1 byte so each 16-bit word access overlaps the previous one.

Comment: A good start for dot product of 16-bit elements would be SSE2 `pmaddwd` to do 8x 16-bit products at once, adding the pairs of results into 32-bit sums, if you want it to be efficient.  (Or for 32-bit elements, [Integer dot product using SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23186348)).  But you should probably read a few more tutorial to learn the basics of scalar before you play with SIMD.

Comment: Also related: ["invalid instruction operands" on mov ah, word\_variable, and using imul on 16-bit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39581293) in actual asm

Comment: And BTW, you know you forgot an `imul` instruction, right?  You're copying src to dst, and adding both pointers very inefficiently (into a memory destination).  So nothing that your loop does is what you want.  (Even beyond all the bugs with random choice of 16-bit address and operand-size that either can't work or don't match your data)

Comment: I am working on it guys thanks for the tips <3